# How can I make stopwatch in C# that displays only seconds and milliseconds?

Tags: c#, winforms, timer

So I want to make a timer that does this: each time I click the button this happens:

> 0.052
>
> 0.521
>
> 1.621
>
> 2.151
>
> ...

But instead of that it goes like this:

> 0.015
>
> 0.032
>
> 0.112
>
> 0.252
>
> ...

This is happening:
[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/09At2.png)

This code is not correct, I waits a long time until it makes a sec..

```
int sec = 0, ms = 1;
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer1.Start();
    listBox1.Items.Add(label1.Text);
    timer1.Interval = 1;

}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ms++;
    if (ms >= 1000)
    {
        sec++;
        ms = 0;

    }
    label1.Text = String.Format("{0:0}.{1:000}", sec, ms);
}
```

Comment: The GUI thread has to update `label1` 1000 times per second? Yeah, no. Use a bigger interval. Leave some time to have the thread do the painting.

Comment: The default timer resolution on Windows is 15.6 milliseconds.

Comment: It is just a presentation mistake, nobody is ever interested in intermediary values.  You have a guarantee that your UI updates at least 64 times per second, that is plenty good enough to fool human eyes.  Just update the label, lose the listbox.  If you want it to be accurate to an atomic clock then use actual elapsed wallclock time so any delays in the OS calling your Tick event handler plays no role.  Use Environment.TickCount.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use a Stopwatch object from the System.Diagnostics namespace of the .Net framework.  Like this:

```
System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

public void button1_Click()
{
    sw.Start;  // start the stopwatch
    // do work
    ...

    sw.Stop;  // stop the stopwatch

    // display stopwatch contents
    label1.Text = string.Format({0}, sw.Elapsed);
}
```

If you want to see the total time elapsed as total seconds and milliseconds only (no minutes or hours), you can change that final line to:

```
label1.Text = string.Format({0}, sw.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000.0)
```

Comment: or using interpolated strings `label1.Text = $"{sw.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000.0}";`

Comment: @flkes - great if user is using C# 6.